# How long does antibiotic-dosed LB maintain good selection?

Tags: cell-culture

Various people in our lab will prepare a liter or so of LB, add kanamycin to 25-37 mg/L for selection, and store it at 4 °C for minipreps or other small cultures (where dosing straight LB with a 1000X stock is troublesome).  Some think using it after more than a week is dubious, but we routinely use kan plates that are 1-2 months old with no ill effect.

How long can LB with antibiotic such as kanamycin, chloramphenicol, or ampicillin be stored at 4 °C and maintain selection?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This Bitesize Bio article](http://bitesizebio.com/articles/ye-olde-antibiotic-plates/) is very informative on this issue.  [The 1970 study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC376956/) they cite found negligible reduction in the the efficacy of non-beta-lactam antibiotics (kanamycin, chloramphenicol) over spans of 4 weeks or 60 days.  Ampicillin loses about 10% activity at 4 weeks.

In my lab, we only take care not to use LB/Amp plates that are older then 4 weeks, for LB/Km, we store them at 4 °C for more then a month, sealed in a plastic bag.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, that is fine.  Thats the temperature that Amp is regularly stored at.  I always do a negative control anyways to ensure that my antibiotics are still lethal.  Just don't stick it in the microwave to make plates

Comment: Ampicillin degrades by hydrolysis (albeit very slowly if not catalyzed), difficult when in dry, much easier when in solution.

Comment: "That's the temperature that Amp is regularly stored at" - and in fact, Amp does lose activity (a few % per month?) as a consequence.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about solutions, but we keep LB-Amp/Carb/Gm plates in 4°C for two-three weeks at a time, and the antibiotics seem to work.